# How to trigger hasLayout on this li for IE 7 white space bug

Tags: css, html-lists, internet-explorer-7, haslayout

**Here's the HTML part of it:**

```
<nav id="main-navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">lorem ipsium lorem ipsium lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">lorem ipsium lorem lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">lorem ipsium lorem ipsium lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">lorem ipsium lorem</a></li>                     
</ul>
</nav>
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
#main-navigation ul li a {    
    display:block;
    font-size: .8em;
    background: lime url("http://www.hpp.moh.gov.sg/HPP/MungoBlobs/636/378/bullets_doctors.gif") no-repeat right center;
    border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
    color:#000; 
    padding: 2px 0;
}

#main-navigation ul li a.last {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}


#main-navigation ul li a:hover,
#main-navigation ul li a:focus,
#main-navigation ul li a:active{
    background: red url("http://www.hpp.moh.gov.sg/HPP/MungoBlobs/636/378/bullets_doctors.gif") no-repeat right center;
    color:#fff
}
```

I wish not to change the html markup.

If you see this on good browsers and then on IE 7, you will see that the LI items on IE7 have a lot of white space between them.

I've tried to apply height:1px; on **a** on a IE only css related file. No luck.

How can one properly trigger the hasLayout so that the white space bug could go away?

Comment: define `margin` on `#main-navigation ul li`

Comment: I've heard that `position: relative` or `zoom: 1` can trigger hasLayout, but I did not test them in your example.

Comment: thanks. #main will change the look and feel no? The solution I found was to declare display inline-block to the li a, and then, re-declare the display property by copying the li a selection and place block; instead. Idiotic. As IE7 idiotic white space bug. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

**HTML part:**

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="badbrowser.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

**CSS part of badbrowser.css :**

```
/* Fix for vertical list LI white space - hasLayout trigger */
#main-navigation li a {
    display:inline-block;
}

#main-navigation li a {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block` helped me with IE8, the `zoom: 1` fix wasn't working on a span

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to set `vertical-align: bottom;` on list items.